# How to show "Not Found" message when someone enters wrong input?

Tags: javascript

### I am working on a project of dictionary, here i have a problem, the problem is - when i search a word which doesn't have any meaning,it doesn't show anything, even in javascript (description.innerHTML = "Not found";) is written. How I fix this problem?

```
  const txtBox = document.querySelector(".txtBox");
const form = document.querySelector(".searchForm");
const searchWord = document.querySelector(".search-word");
const description = document.querySelector(".description");
const dictionaryJson =
  "\dictionary.json";
function searchDict(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(dictionaryJson)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      e.preventDefault;
      let word = txtBox.value;
      console.log(txtBox.value);
      let searchKeyword = word.toUpperCase();
      Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        if (key === searchKeyword) {
          searchWord.innerHTML = searchKeyword;
          if(searchKeyword === data[key]){
            description.innerHTML = "Not found";
          }
          else{
             description.innerHTML = data[key];
          }
          
          console.log(data[key]);
        }
        
      });
    });
}

form.addEventListener("submit", searchDict);
```

Comment: Provide sample value for `data` if possible. That will be useful to analyze the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to change InnerHTML with InnerText.

Comment: It doesn't work, sir